# Python list item printing with brackets

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

1. I initiated a series of variables with values
2. I put these variables in a list
3. I tried to print the values in a while loop trying both...

   data[0] and str(data[0])
4. The issue that this data is printing with the list [] brackets, this does not happen if I directly print the variable before passing it into a list — which I will functionally have to do for this program

My code:

```
# initiate data 

    # personal info
        businessName = "//*[@id='BusinessName']"
        firstName = "//*[@id='BusinesOwnersFirstName']"
        lastName = "//*[@id='BusinesOwnersLastName']"
        ubi = "//*[@id='UBINumber']"
        info = "//*[@id='persInfoContainer']"

    # liscensing info
        licenseType = "//*[@id='LicenseType']"
        specialties = "//*[@id='layoutContainer']/div[5]/div[6]/label[1]"
        licenseNumber = "//*[@id='LicenseNumber']"
        licenseEffectiveDate = "//*[@id='EffectiveDate']"
        licenseExpirationDate = "//*[@id='ExpirationDate']']/div[5]/div[6]/label[2]"
        status = "//*[@id='StatusDescription']"

    # bond info
        bondProvider = "//*[@id='BondsCompanyName']"
        bondNumber = "//*[@id='BondAccountNumber']"
        bondAmount = "//*[@id='BondAmount']"
        bondEffectiveDate = "//*[@id='BondsEffectiveDate']"
        bondExpirationDate = "//*[@id='BondsExpirationDate']" 

        # insurance info
        insuranceProvider = "//*[@id='InsurancesFirmName']"
        insuranceNumber = "//*[@id='InsurancesAccountId']"
        insuranceAmount = "//*[@id='InsurancesAmount']"
        insuranceEffectiveDate = "//*[@id='InsurancesEffectiveDate']"
        insuranceExpirationDate = "//*[@id='InsurancesExpirationDate']"


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

# data list
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
        data = [
        [businessName],[firstName],[lastName],[ubi],[info],
        [licenseType],[specialties],[licenseNumber],[licenseEffectiveDate],[licenseExpirationDate],[status],
        [bondProvider],[bondNumber],[bondAmount],[bondEffectiveDate],[bondEffectiveDate],[insuranceProvider],
        [insuranceNumber],[insuranceAmount],[insuranceEffectiveDate],[insuranceExpirationDate]
        ] 

        # print data


# needed logic outlne:
#     get list 
#         loop thorugh checking is xpath is available
#             if not available set dataOut to ""
#             else get xpathData and set dataOut to xpathData
#                 export to csv file




# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# xpath check and grab function
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        i = 0
        l = len(data)-1
        while (i <= l):
            print "string: "+ str(data[0])
            print "non-string: "+ data[0]
            try:
                # self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(data[i]) #checks is xpath exists
                # return True
                result = browser.find_element_by_xpath(data[0]).text
                print "result"+result
            except:
                # return False
                print "ERROR: empty xpath"
            i += 1
```

My output(in command line):

```
string: ["//*[@id='BusinessName']"]
print "non-string: "+ data[0]
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put each string into a singleton `list` for some reason, so (as the error says) `data[0]` is, itself, a `list`. If you want the string contained in that `list`, access it with `data[0][0]` (or whatever appropriate index is needed, assuming you ever add to the `list`s in `data`). You could use either `+` or `,` for this one.

```
print "non-string: " + data[0][0]
```

You can also print the object itself by having `print` process each object separately (with `,` rather than `+`) instead of attempting to concatenate them:

```
print "non-string:", data[0]
```

Note that this will result in a `list` being printed, complete with square brackets, e.g. `non-string: ["//*[@id='BusinessName']"]`.

However, I'd recommend doing away with those singleton `list`s as follows (unless you really need them for some reason):

```
data = [
    businessName, firstName, ...
```

Then `data[0]` will be a string.

Comment: Currently implementing your suggestions now with great success! Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little confusing on if you are trying to print the list, concatenate a string, or send the element into the function find.element_by_x_path but I will try the best I can. It also depends on what Python version you are using (recommend Python 3 :) ) You are getting the TypeError because Python can't concatenate a string and a list object. If you just want to print the data list use a simple 'for' loop

```
for item in data:
   print (item)
```

If you want to concatenate in your while loop above try something like

```
for string in data: # Takes list into iterable objects
    newstring = string + "something here"
    print (string)
```

You can also use Python's built in "type" to help you out with the variables to make sure you passing in what you want to pass in to your find.element_by_xpath

```
type(data)
<<<    <class 'list'>
```

Also there could be an indexing error with the type of strings you are doing making a list of list "[][]"

Try switching the input to data[0][0] or run it through Python's type command to see if that's what you want

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer only contains code and information that are already present in the question (I'm not even sure why you're suggesting the exact kind of concatenation that produced an error and prompted the question in the first place) and/or in an older answer.

Comment: Tigerhawk, I wasn't sure exactly what he was trying to accomplish so I gave him several options that might be possible solutions to help in the long run. Indeed your answer is probably more accurate on his exact problem now that I understand. We both mention that data[0][0] is what he wants or as you suggested use a singleton list. data[]
Sorry for my ignorance